# How to run my python script parallely with another Java application on the same Linux box in Gitlab CI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, gitlab

For one gitlab CI runner
I have a jar file which needs to be continuosly running in the Git linux box but since this is a application which is continuosly running, the python script in the next line is not getting executed. How to run the jar application and then execute the python script simultaneously one after another?

`.gitlab.ci-yml` file:

```
pwd && ls -l
unzip ZAP_2.8.0_Core.zip && ls -l
bash scan.sh
python3 Report.py
```

`scan.sh` file has the code `java -jar app.jar`.

Since, this application is continuosly running, 4th line code `python3 Report.py` is not getting executed.

How do I make both these run simulataneously without the .jar application stopping?

Comment: Step one: Find out what programming language (perhaps a shell like BASH or the POSIX shell) that uses. Then, find out how to run things in parallel there. If you remove git, gitlab, Python and  Java from your question, it's just about running two processes in parallel there. That would make your question more concise, smaller and give you the base for better online searches! As a new user here, please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Understood! I will try to be concise. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate solution would probably be:

```
pwd && ls -l
echo "ls OK"
unzip ZAP_2.8.0_Core.zip && ls -l
echo "unzip + ls OK"
bash scan.sh &
scanpid=$!
echo "started scanpid with pid $scanpid"]
ps axuf | grep $scanpid || true
echo "ps + grep OK"
( python3 Report.py ; echo $? > report_status.txt ) || true 
echo "report script OK"
kill $scanpid
echo "kill OK"
echo "REPORT STATUS = $(cat report_status.txt)"
test $(cat report_status.txt) -eq 0
```

Start the java process in the background, 
run your python code and remember its return status and always return true. 
kill the background process after running python
check for the status code of the python script.

Perhaps this is not necessary, as I never checked how gitlabci deals with background processes, that were spawned by its runners.

I do here a conservative approach.
 - I remember the process id of the bash script, so that I can kill it later
 - I ensure, that the line running the python script always returns a 0 exit code such, that gitlabci does not stop executing the next lines, but I remember the status code
 - then I kill the bash script
 - then I check whether the exit code of the python script was 0 or not, such, that gitlabci can perform the proper checking whether the runner was executed successfully or not.

Another minor comment (not related to your question)

I don't really understand why you write

```
unzip ZAP_2.8.0_Core.zip && ls -l
```

instead of

````
unzip ZAP_2.8.0_Core.zip ; ls -l```
````

If you expect the unzip command  to fail you could just write

```
unzip ZAP_2.8.0_Core.zip
ls -l
```

and gitlabci would abort automatically before executing `ls -l`

I also added many echo statements for better debugging, error analysis, you might remove them  in your final solution.

Comment: I tried this and yet only the application is running and the python script is not getting executed.

Comment: The application is running but the python script afterwards is not getting executed. So, no scope of shutdown.

Comment: Could you add an  `echo` line as every second line and report back what result yo get in the reporting of the gitlab ci runner. What is the last line being executed?

Comment: added some echo statements for debugging.
Please post the eact output of your gitlabci runner after having added all the lines in my answer.

This gives hopefully enough info to locate the (or at least the first) issue

Answer (score 0):

To run the two scripts one after the other, you can add `&` to the end of the line that is blocking. That will make it run in the background.

Either do 
`bash scan.sh &` or add `&` to the end of the line calling the jar file within the scan.sh...